# SAS - conditional macro variable

Tags: if-statement, macros, sas

I have a variable date=201611 and I need to create the first day of the next month in the following format '2016-12-01'. The following code works fine for the months up till 11:

```
%let date = 201611;
%let rok = %sysfunc(substr(&date,1,4));
%let month = %sysfunc(substr(&date,5,2));
%let xdat2_ii = &rok-%eval(&month + 1)-01;
%let xdat1 = %str(%')&xdat2_ii.%str(%');
%put &xdat1;
'2016-12-01'
```

I need to add some improvement to make the code working for the month 12, i.e. when the date is 201612 then to obtain '2017-01-01'.

My idea was to do it using macro, but it does not work.

```
%macro promenne;
%if &month < 12 %then %let xdat2_ii = &rok-%eval(&month + 1)-01 
%else %if &month= 12 %then %let xdat2_ii = %eval(&rok + 1)-01-01;
%mend promenne;
```

Thank you for any suggestions which way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with dates, is often easiest to use the built in date shifting functions - in this case, [intnx](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm).

```
/* define variable (this is a macro STRING) */
%let date=201612;

/* convert to SAS date value (numeric, num of days since 01JAN1960) */
%let dateval=%sysfunc(mdy(%substr(&date,5,2),1,%substr(&date,1,4)));

/* finally - shift to beginning of following month and format output */
%let xdat2_ii=%sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dateval,1,B),yymmddd10.);

%put &xdat2_ii;  /* 2017-01-01 */
```